# Show a username in stead of the user id with foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of games where the home_team_user_id and away_team_user_id each has a user_id assigned to it trough foreign keys.

The game only stores the both user id's but now in the gamelist I want to show the username in stead of the user_id.

wrong sollution direct in the view:

```
<%= User.find(game.home_team_user_id).email %>
```

This works but if a user is not found it throws an error.

I want to move this logic to the controller but I can't seem to manage.

GAMES CONTROLLER:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @games = Game.all
        @home_team_username = User.select(:id, :username).find(game.home_user)
        @away_team_username = User.select(:id, :username).find(game.away_user)
    end
```

MODELS:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    #RELATIONS SINGLE GAMES

     has_many :home_games,    class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'home_team_user_id'
     has_many :away_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'away_team_user_id'
    end


class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

        belongs_to :home_user,    class_name: "User", foreign_key: "home_team_user_id"
        belongs_to :away_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "away_team_user_id"


end
```

VIEW:

```
<% @games.each do |game|%> 
                 <tbody> 
                     <td><%= game.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y - %Hh%M")%></td>

            <% if game.home_score == game.away_score  %>
                     <td style="background-color: #e67300"><%= @home_team_username.username %></td>
                      <td style="background-color: #e67300"><%= game.home_score %></td>

                     <% elsif game.home_score > game.away_score  %>
                     <td style="background-color: #66ff33"><%= @home_team_username.username %></td>
                      <td style="background-color: #66ff33"><%= game.home_score %></td>

         <% elsif game.home_score < game.away_score %>

                     <td style="background-color: #ff1a1a"><%= @home_team_username.username %></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #ff1a1a"><%= game.home_score %></td>

         <% end %>
                     <td style="text-align: center">-</td>

            <% if game.home_score == game.away_score  %>
                        <td style="background-color: #e67300"><%= game.away_score %></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #e67300"><%= @away_team_username.username %></td>

         <% elsif game.home_score < game.away_score  %>
                        <td style="background-color: #66ff33"><%= game.away_score %></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #66ff33"><%= @away_team_username.username %></td>

         <% elsif game.home_score > game.away_score %>

                        <td style="background-color: #ff1a1a"><%= game.away_score %></td>
                     <td style="background-color: #ff1a1a"><%= @away_team_username.username %></td>

         <% end %>
```

I think this should work but it shows an error:

> undefined local variable or method `game' for

For some reason it can't use the game variable from the loop in the view.

Whats the correct way for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to use `game` in the index action in the controller, but it's not defined here for a single game. The right way to do it in my opinion is just set all games in the controller:

```
def index
  @games = Game.all
end
```

And then just get the name in the view like this for example:

```
<td style="background-color: #e67300"><%= game.homeuser.username %></td>
```

To show 'Deleted user' you could assign the variables at the beginning of the loop, like this:

```
home_user_name = if game.homeuser.present?
                   game.homeuser.username
                 else
                   'Deleted user'
                 end
```

Or in one line:

```
home_user_name = game.homeuser.try(:username).presence || 'Deleted user'
```

And then use this:

```
<td style="background-color: #e67300"><%= home_user_name %></td>
```

Comment: This works! But it still errors if a user is deleted while his id is still in the games list. This should show deleted user then...

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to show in the index? Do you want all the users for all  the games?

> ```
> @home_team_username = User.select(:id, :username).find(game.home_user)
> ```

Can be replaced with this

```
@home_team_username = game.home_user
```

`game.home_user` IS a user. You can then return the username of that object.

Also, I would either rename the variable `@home_team_username` to `@home_team_user`, or store the `username` (not the user) and pass that to the views.

Comment: It still shows the same error " undefined local variable or method `game' for #<GamesController:0xbef5b10> "
I think the connection between the loop in the view where the variable game is set doesn't connect with the controller...

Comment: I want to show all games. 
each game has a home_team_id and away_team_id but in the view this has to show the corresponding user in this list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you seems to be using a game variable which is not declared (method `GamesController#index`, line 2).